# Checking my pc's Windows Phone 8 emulator compatibility

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

Windows Phone 8 SDK setup gives a warning that says I can not run Windows Phone 8 emulator on my PC since it does not support hardware virtualization. The annoying thing is, it gives this error at the end of the setup process, after it has everything installed.

It there a utility program that can check for that compatibility **before** installing SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's described here in detail:

http://www.howtogeek.com/73318/how-to-check-if-your-cpu-supports-second-level-address-translation-slat/